# Sending a SOAP request with Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, soap, windows-phone-8

I have a SOAP 1.1 or 1.2 service that I want to use in order to query some data from a Windows Phone 8 app.  The problem is, I haven't got the slightest notion about how to do this.

The SOAP request is already provided, I simply do not know how to use it.  I've tried adding a WebService but I'm sort of fumbling in the dark as the SOAP request is provided from a 3rd party with little or no documentation and little or no possibility of getting any either.

I've pasted in the SOAP request below.  I'd need basic step by step instructions about how to use this and get some sort of a response from it.

```
POST /RTPIService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: rtpi.sample.servers.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://testsite.com/GetRealTimeStopData"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
    <GetRealTimeStopData xmlns="http://testsite.com/">
      <stopId>int</stopId>
      <forceRefresh>boolean</forceRefresh>
    </GetRealTimeStopData>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow bellow step

**Step1:** Add Service References by right click on add References.

**Step2:** Now put your web service link on Service References and press go button, And also add Namespace of service Reference
[image]

**Step3:** Press go buton it will take autometically all method of web service

Now add bellow code in your cs file its for example

```
 WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient ws = new WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient();
ws.ContactUsJSONCompleted += ws_ContactUsJSONCompleted;
ws.ContactUsJSONAsync(txtContactUsName.Text, txtContactUsPhone.Text, txtContactUsEmail.Text, txtContactUsComment.Text);
```

**step6:** now genrate your resopnce method

```
 void ws_ContactUsJSONCompleted(object sender, dynamic e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(LogIn.NetworkBusyMsg, LogIn.MsgHdr, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                busyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            }
            else
            {
                busyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                string Result = e.Result;
                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(Result);
                string ResultCode = (string)obj["ResultCode"];
                string ResponceMessage = (string)obj["ResponseMessage"];

                if (ResultCode == "1")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Thank you for your message. We'll get back to you soon.", LogIn.MsgHdr, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    NavigationService.GoBack();
                }
                else
                {
    
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help you.

If any query than comment here.I wll help you

Comment: Thanks.

I'm making some progress however this apparently is the type of response that's due to be returned although I'm not sure what to do with it or how to process it:

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetRealTimeStopDataResponse xmlns="http://testsite.com/">
      <GetRealTimeStopDataResult>xmlxml</GetRealTimeStopDataResult>
    </GetRealTimeStopDataResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>

Comment: first you have web service URL?...if yes than put this URL in to service reference address bar and give name of service as per your convince...than follow step3 if any confusion let me know ....ignore content type and all this thing

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still a bit confused.  I think the response I'm getting is some sort of XML but I don't really know what to do with it or what the next step is.

Comment: It's actually the error section of the code sample above that is being fired, so it's finding some sort of error when it checks if (e.Error != null)

Comment: Actually, I think I read the code wrong.  There is no error being fired.  I think it's returning information but I don't know what.  How can I see the actual data being returned?

Comment: in else part you can manage your actual data if any query let me know

Comment: In my example i parse json data if you have xml data than write same code but the way of parsing is diffrent

Comment: The problem is that I can't even see what it is returning.  I don't think I can cast whatever is returned as a string.

Comment: ok now tell me you complete up to stap 3? like service method method name and pass parameter and every thing.....if yes tell me what is event argument of value?......

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to use a SOAP service

```
-- Create a new project or Open Your Project.
-- Right-click on the Project name and click on "Add Service Reference"...
   Then provide address as "http://testsite.com/RTPIService.asmx" and click Go.
-- Once service information is downloaded, provide Namespace something like
   "MyRTPIService" at the bottom and click Ok.
```

Now that your proxy classes should be ready.
Go to your Mainpage.xaml.cs and type 'MyRTPIService.' there..you should probably get a  list of classes of all the services provided by the SOAP service.

If you get that, then try to call the suitable methods of that class.

For an example,

```
MyRTPIServiceClient client = new MyRTPIServiceClient();
client.GetRealTimeStopDataCompleted += new EventHandler<GetRealTimeStopDataCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetRealTimeStopDataCompleted);
client.GetRealTimeStopDataAsync();
```

Also, define a event handler of `client_GetRealTimeStopDataCompleted`

Good luck !!

Comment: @irldev Forget all that you did and follow the above steps and relate them to your service. It works !!

Comment: I know how to add the service, the problem is that I seem to be getting an error when it returns stuff but I don't see what the error is.